# Java-Counting occurrence of word from huge textfile

Tags: java, full-text-search

I have a text file of size 115MB.  It consists of about 20 million words.  I have to use the file as a word collection, and use it to search the occurrence of each user-given words from the collection.  I am using this process as a small part in my project.  I need a method for finding out the  number of occurrence of given words in a faster and correct manner since i may use it in iterations. I am in need of suggestion about any API that i can make use or some other way that performs the task in a quicker manner. Any recommendations are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of thing is typically implemented using [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html), especially if you are going to be restarting your application repeatedly or you don't have oodles of memory.  Lucene supports [lots of other goodies](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/features.html) too.

However, if you wanted to "roll your own" code, and you have enough memory (probably 1Gb), your application could:

- parse the file into sequence of words,
- filter out stopwords,
- build a "reverse index" as a `HashMap<String, List<Integer>>`, where the `String` values are the unique words, and the `List<Integer>` objects give the offsets of the words' occurrences in the file.

It could take a few seconds (or minutes) to process a file that big.  But once you've created the in-memory reverse index you can do an occurrence search very quickly.  (Maybe sub-microsecond per search.)

Comment: I'd say that he even does not need Map<String, List<Integer>>. He just needs Map<String, Integer> that stores counter of occurrences.

Comment: @AlexR - its unclear.  At one point the OP says he needs the "occurrence".  I interpreted that as meaning "occurrenceS".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the posts.I got my job done using lucene indexing.I used lucene freq() method to retrieve the frequency of the indexed terms